# Resize height of DataTable inside a Box in ShinyDashboard

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I'm trying to put some Datatables and Histograms inside boxes of defined height in a Shiny Dashboard, the problem is that when I fix the height (lets say, to 250), the datatable exceeds the limits.

I know we have "autowidth" to use with datatables, but havent seen nothing similar for the Height. I tried to fix the height of the datatable too, but that didn't work for me neither. Also, when I open the shiny in a smaller screen, the box would resize, but the datatable don't.

Here's an example of the problem

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmltools)


ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black", title = "Dashboard",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
                    dashboardSidebar(width = 300),

                    dashboardBody(

                      tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                                            div.box {
                                            text-align: center;
                                            border-style: solid;
                                            border-bottom-color:red;
                                            border-left-color:red;
                                            border-right-color:red;
                                            border-top-color:red;
                                            border-bottom-width:20px;
                                            border-top-width:20px;   
                                            border-left-width:20px;
                                            border-right-width:20px;
                                            }
                  "))),


                      box(title = "Resume", width = 4, column(12, withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput("tab"))),
                          align="center", status = "danger",solidHeader = T,height=250)
))
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$tab <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(head(iris),options=list("autoWidth"=TRUE, "pagelength"=15,"scrollY"=TRUE,"scrollX"=TRUE,"searching"=FALSE))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Actually ScrollX works perfectly, why scrollY doesnt work aswell?
I read about using tabBox instead of Box, but that doesnt work neither. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput("tab", height = '240px')`, currently your code is setting the height of the box, not the data table.

Also, try `style = "overflow-x: scroll;"` in the `box()` arguments for the scrolling

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But had to change "overflow-y" not "x". Anyways, thanks for your help!